# Windows 11 Explorer Crashing When Hovering Over Snap Layout

Tags: layout, explorer, snap

After upgrading windows 10 to windows 11 whenever I hover over the snap layout (maximize button) windows explorer would crash and restart and I wouldn't be able to use the snap layout. I've updated my drivers and look around but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What fixed it for me is changing the scale to 100% apparently, I had it set to 110%.

Here are few other things to try.

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-file-explorer-crashes-after-resizing-or-snapping-in-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Changing the scale to 100% worked for me also.

Head to Settings > System > Display

Answer (score 0):

I just made a nice discovery that might make this solution a little more palatable. I had my scaling set to 128%. If I changed it to 100% it would make it very difficult to see some things on my 4K screen.

I thought maybe I could try a number a little less odd than 128, so I tried 125% and it worked! So play around with it a bit if you don't want to use 100%. There might be other values that work as well.